# Audit To Database Plugin - Jenkins : org.hibernate.HibernateException

Tags: java, jenkins, database-connection

I want to use the Audit to Database Plugin to record the build information to database. I have installed the plugin properly and I user the following config:

```
JDBC Driver class: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver**

JDBC Url:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jenkins_audit?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
```

But when I clicked the **Test Connection** Button, I got this:

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver`

My question is how to solve this problem,  and is there any other way to store the jenkins build information to mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

You´re using a wrong driver, you have to use MySQL driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: But currently the plugin just support these drivers:org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: You´re connecting to a MYSQl database looking the second URL that you posted. So, you have to use MYSQl drivers trust me.

Comment: And if I use com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, I got this:org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Try to google on that. But can you try something like this, changing with you URL  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");
conn.close();

Comment: So I think it may be the jenkins' issue, Thank you all the same.